# unexpected java.io.FileNotFoundException error at the Jenkins performance plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins, performance-testing

Installed the performance plugin at Jenkins server with version 2.263.3 Run the jmeter performance test job by Pipeline, and everything works as expected. the job finished in SUCCESS status.

But around 40 mins later, the console returned message to resume the build. and it returned FileNotFoundException. This issue occurred at each job run. And we googled some resolution and still no luck. Please anyone can help at this issue. Thank you so much

```
Archiving artifacts
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Generate Test Report)
[Pipeline] perfReport
Creating parser with percentiles:'0,50,90,100,' filterRegex:null
Performance: Recording JMeterCsv reports 'Belong_Jenkins_PerformanceTest/outputFolder/performanceTestResult.jtl'
Performance: JMeterCsv copying reports to master, files '[/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Belong_Digital_Test/PerformanceTest/Belong_Jenkins_PerformanceTest/outputFolder/performanceTestResult.jtl]'
Performance: JMeterCsv parsing local reports '[/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Belong_Digital_Test/jobs/PerformanceTest/builds/72/performance-reports/JMeterCSV/performanceTestResult.jtl]'
Performance: Parsing report file '/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Belong_Digital_Test/jobs/PerformanceTest/builds/72/performance-reports/JMeterCSV/performanceTestResult.jtl' with filterRegex 'null'.
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test unstable
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test failure
Performance: File performanceTestResult.jtl reported 0.036% of errors [SUCCESS]. Build status is: SUCCESS
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Resuming build at Sun May 02 04:31:06 UTC 2021 after Jenkins restart
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Belong_Digital_Test/jobs/PerformanceTest/builds/72/program.dat (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverReader.openStreamAt(RiverReader.java:188)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverReader.restorePickles(RiverReader.java:136)
    at 

    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.loadProgramAsync(CpsFlowExecution.java:784)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.onLoad(CpsFlowExecution.java:750)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getExecution(WorkflowRun.java:691)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.onLoad(WorkflowRun.java:550)
        at hudson.model.RunMap.retrieve(RunMap.java:225)
        at hudson.model.RunMap.retrieve(RunMap.java:57)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.load(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:501)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.load(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:483)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.getByNumber(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:381)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.search(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:346)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.newestBuild(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:276)
        at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.getLastBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:242)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getLastBuild(WorkflowJob.java:240)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getLastBuild(WorkflowJob.java:103)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.JobCollector.appendJobMetrics(JobCollector.java:241)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.JobCollector.lambda$collect$0(JobCollector.java:196)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.util.Jobs.forEachJob(Jobs.java:14)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.JobCollector.collect(JobCollector.java:189)
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:190)
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:223)
        at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:144)
        at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.service.DefaultPrometheusMetrics.collectMetrics(DefaultPrometheusMetrics.java:54)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.prometheus.service.PrometheusAsyncWorker.execute(PrometheusAsyncWorker.java:41)
        at hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork.lambda$doRun$0(AsyncPeriodicWork.java:100)
    Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load build state
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$3.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:865)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$3.onSuccess(CpsFlowExecution.java:863)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution$4$1.run(CpsFlowExecution.java:917)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:38)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2):

After two long years of searching, I have finally discovered the root cause of the issue and devised a solution. Initially, my Jenkins job utilized a pipeline with a K8S pod (container) stack. Upon successful completion of the job, the pod (container) would be terminated. However, Jenkins mistakenly interpreted the removal event as a restart and attempted to resume the build. Consequently, it sought to access the program.dat file in the original container (pod), which had already been deleted after the job's completion. To resolve this, a simple solution is to enable the option 'Do not allow the pipeline to resume if the controller restarts' at the configure of the job. Unfortunately, this approach presents a minor drawback as the job status perpetually displays 'failed', even though it was successful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough data to analyze the root cause of the problem, the very first line tells that **the Jenkins has been restarted during the JMeter job execution** so I wouldn't trust the test results in any case, just re-run the job and assuming your configuration is correct you should see the output, performance trends chart, etc.

More information:

- [Configure Jenkins to Run and Show JMeter Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-and-jmeter)
- [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)

Comment: hi Dmitri T, the job status was success. but after around 40 mins. it returns the message Jenkins restarts and fileNotFound error. I add more log information at the question. please check

Comment: Sounds like you're suffering from [JENKINS-53775](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53775?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)